# Running Code without Shadow Reference(error) Vs Running with Shadow Reference (no error)

Tags: python

I am beginner at Python and have been working through a book to learn the language. I have come across a rather peculiar error when running code with shadow references vs without shadow references. When I run the below code, everything works as expected but it has shadow references (which as I understand it, are not healthy for code)

```
#  create a function that will print text messages
def show_messages(messages):
"""Print text messages"""
    for message in messages:
    print(f"Sending Message: {message}")


#  create a function that will add extra verbiage to the original messages
def add_name(messages):
"""Add 'Bob,' to the beginning of the messages"""
#  build a new list to hold the new messages
    sent_messages = []


#  Add 'Bob,' to the beginning of the messages
while messages:
    text = messages.pop()
    sent_message = f"Bob, {text}"
    sent_messages.append(sent_message)

#  add the new message back into 'messages'
for new_message in sent_messages:
    messages.append(new_message)

return messages

#  create a list of short text messages
messages = ["Hey, what's up?",
            "Do you wanna go to a bar later?",
            "When should we meet up?",
            "Sounds like a plan!"
            ]

#  call the original function to show the original messages
show_messages(messages)

print('\nWith Name:')
#  call the function to print the new messages
new_messages = add_name(messages[:])
show_messages(new_messages)

# call the original function to print the original messages (this only works when shadow 
referencing)
print("\nOriginal Messages:")
show_messages(messages)
```

However if I do not use shadow references when I define my functions like the below then it does not copy my list correctly when I call the add_name function at the bottom:

```
#  create a function that will print text messages
def show_messages(messages_1):
"""Print text messages"""
    for message in messages:
    print(f"Sending Message: {message}")


#  create a function that will add extra verbiage to the original messages
def add_name(messages_1):
"""Add 'Bob,' to the beginning of the messages"""
#  build a new list to hold the new messages
    sent_messages = []


#  Add 'Bob,' to the beginning of the messages
while messages:
    text = messages.pop()
    sent_message = f"Bob, {text}"
    sent_messages.append(sent_message)

#  add the new message back into 'messages'
for new_message in sent_messages:
    messages.append(new_message)

return messages

#  create a list of short text messages
messages = ["Hey, what's up?",
            "Do you wanna go to a bar later?",
            "When should we meet up?",
            "Sounds like a plan!"
            ]

#  call the original function to show the original messages
show_messages(messages)

print('\nWith Name:')
#  call the function to print the new messages
new_messages = add_name(messages[:])
show_messages(new_messages)

# call the original function to print the original messages (this only works when shadow 
referencing)
print("\nOriginal Messages:")
show_messages(messages)
```

Why does the code with shadow references work but the code without shadow references cause an error?

Comment: Neither of these examples is a [mre]; you have a stray `return messages`, and you also have `while messages:` before `messages` is even defined. It's impossible to just paste this code into an IDE and run it. Also, your second example has `messages_1` as the args to some functions but the functions never use it, which I don't understand either.

Comment: It would be a big help if you could [edit] your code to fix the numerous indentation errors. It's not at all clear what you mean by "shadow reference". I assume it would become clear from the difference between the two versions of your code, but the difference is too subtle for me. I can't see any difference (and since the code can't be run, due to the indentation issues, I can't test for myself).